# find corresponding cell depending on other cell

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to get the value of a cell depending on the value entered in another cell. I have different sheets in my workbook :

- Sheet 1: One with a list of people and adresses
- Sheet 2: One with a list of orders from these people

In Sheet 2, when I choose a client's name from the dropdown list (created via data-validation list with sheet 1), I'd like his address to display automatically in another cell (same row, different column).

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

A simple vlookup will do this. Assuming you have the dropdown in A2 of Sheet2, put this in Sheet2 in the column you want the address in. If you have a dropdown in each row, drag the formula down:

```
=iferror(vlookup(A2,Sheet1!A2:B4,2,false))
```